# React native Axios Django - Csrf failed referer checking failed no referer

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, axios, django-csrf

I am calling a `Django` back-end api from `React` front-end using axios.

For that api which is login api, I am using Django Knox package in logic.

*React.js* - I am calling `axios.request(method, url, data)` and the api call is working correctly.
When I went to `Developer tools`>`Network`, I can see `Referer` header set to React.js website in request header and no other csrf-related header. In Response headers I can see two `set-cookie` headers, `csrftoken` and `sessionid.`

*React Native* - same way I am calling api but api returns error `csrf failed referer checking failed - no referer` . When I checked `response.config`, `Referer` header is not set unlike React.js

*Curl* - works fine

*httpie* - works fine

How can I get rid of this error.

*Note 1* - My Django back-end is based on api token logic and not csrf in any way.

*Note 2* - React.js and Django are hosted on different domains. I am facing error in React Native  which is in debug mode.

*Update 1* - After disabling CSRF middleware in Django settings.py, now I am getting only one setCookie header (csrftoken is no longer obtained) but same error still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django Rest api need a Referer header.

In case of React.js it is automatically set (maybe by browser) and its value is current website.

But in case of React Native, it is not set. so we have to manually set it.

1. From this [link](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/211#issuecomment-362449299), i set Referer header in axios. see below code

```
export const axiosAPICall = (method,url,data,headers) => {
    let request = {
        method: method,
        url: url,
    };
    if (data) {
        request['data'] = data;
    }
    if (headers) {
        request['headers'] = headers;
    }
    // Referer is auto-set in react.js as same website value.
    // for react-native we have to set it manually to target api:port
    request['headers'] = {
        ...request['headers'],
        Referer: url
    }
    return axios.request(request)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(error => {throw error});
};
```

2. In Django `settings.py`, I commented `CSRF middleware`
3. In Django `settings.py`, I added only `TokenAuthentication` class to remove `SessionAuthentication`.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Note - Please do steps 2 and 3 at your risk after knowing your requirements properly. I removed CSRF middleware because my API was completely dependent on token for auth. I did not need CSRF in any way.